# Как записать значения из массива в файл? В данном коде записует но какой-то мусор

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

[image: То что записалось в файл]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Teacher[] Personteachers = new Teacher[100];
    private Student[] Personstudents = new Student[100];
    private TimetableStudent[] TimeTableStudent = new TimetableStudent[100];
    private TimetableTeacher[] TimeTableTeacher = new TimetableTeacher[100];

    private void Start()
    {
        Personteachers[0] = new Teacher("Александр Пушкин", 42, "Male", new DateTime(1981, 5, 12), "Продвинутий", "Ist-21d", "Декан");
        Personteachers[1] = new Teacher("Мария Османова", 38, "Female", new DateTime(1985, 12, 20), "Продвинутый", "Ipz-19d", "Провесор");
        Personteachers[2] = new Teacher("Осман Арсений", 41, "Male", new DateTime(1982, 9, 1), "Начинающий", "App-61k", "Ректор");
        Personteachers[3] = new Teacher("Джо Смит", 33, "Female", new DateTime(1990, 4, 2), "Средний", "IS-16l", "Професор");
        Personteachers[4] = new Teacher("Орео Кинг", 40, "Male", new DateTime(1983, 11, 10), "Продвинутый", "Rtz-01p", "Преподаватель");
        Personteachers[5] = new Teacher("Аманда Стоун", 29, "Female", new DateTime(1994, 6, 2), "Продвинутый", "Up-12q", "Преподаватель");

        Personstudents[0] = new Student("Павел Воля", 21, "Male", new DateTime(2002, 5, 12), "Itk-21d", 2, 1);
        Personstudents[1] = new Student("Мария Османова", 20, "Female", new DateTime(2003, 12, 20), "Upi-20d", 3, 0);
        Personstudents[2] = new Student("Александр Пушкин", 23, "Male", new DateTime(2000, 9, 1), "Ist-22d", 1, 2);
        Personstudents[3] = new Student("Банда Ричард", 20, "Female", new DateTime(2003, 4, 2), "Koi-21d", 3, 1);
        Personstudents[4] = new Student("Арсений Понамарев", 21, "Male", new DateTime(2002, 11, 10), "Uzu-22d", 2, 3);
        Personstudents[5] = new Student("Аманда Стоун", 22, "Female", new DateTime(2001, 6, 2), "Nara-22d", 2, 0);

        TimeTableStudent[0] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Astro", "Abserve 10", "Том Боб", "PD-21d");
        TimeTableStudent[1] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Science", "Lab 5", "Аманда Криста", "PP-20d");
        TimeTableStudent[2] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Economy", "Zoom 4", "Омана Кара", "AS-22d");
        TimeTableStudent[3] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "English", "Teams 16", "Ягами Лайт", "Tr-20d");
        TimeTableStudent[4] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Projects", "Zoom 1", "Джули Ким", "AR-22d");
        TimeTableStudent[5] = new TimetableStudent(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Sport", "Sport ground", "Доктор Парс", "NS-22d");

        TimeTableTeacher[0] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Math", "None", "Джун Ким", "Геометрия");
        TimeTableTeacher[1] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "History", "Lab 5", "Сол Гудман", "Древний Рим");
        TimeTableTeacher[2] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Macro", "Zoom 8", "Джеси Пинк", "Бактерии");
        TimeTableTeacher[3] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "English", "Room 4", "Том Джонсон", "Времена");
        TimeTableTeacher[4] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Projects", "Zoom 1", "Джули Найт", "Проектирование");
        TimeTableTeacher[5] = new TimetableTeacher(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "Sport", "ground", "Джо Смит", "Футбол");

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("students.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            foreach (object element in Personstudents)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Start();           
    }
```

Comment: А что хотите получить то? Можно так, без цикла и стримрайтера одной строкой `File.WriteAllText("students.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(Personstudents));`

Comment: Так а вы чем смотрите результат? Если блокнотом, так он utf8 не понимает

Comment: @CrazyElf да там просто `Object.ToString()` отрабатывает. Блокнот прекрасно понимает UTF-8. Хотя от версии винды возможно зависит. Если XP, то конечно же вряд-ли.

Comment: _Не пишите и не вызывайте никогда свой код в конструкторе формы. Для кода, выполняющегося при старте приложения в Winforms есть обработчик события `Form.Load`. Чтобы он появился, нажмите двойным кликом по пустому месту на форме в дизайнере формы._

Comment: @aepot Код вообще компилятор не считывает ваш. Та и я не пойму что это вообще... Мне нужно просто текст с массива записать туда, или накрайняк в байтах а потом я считаю. Просто код изменять не могу - возможно то что явного указания типа нет в массиве и нужно его как-то преобразовать?

Comment: `using System.Text.Json;` добавьте, это же просто должно быть. Это и есть преобразование, сериализация называется https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to Нашел у себя опечатку, исправил `WriteAllText`

Comment: @aepot Увидел, но это точно Си шарп? Даже такую библеотеку не подключает)

Comment: Версия .NET какая у вас?

Comment: @aepot .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Это древний фреймворк, поэтому и не поддерживается штатный сериализатор. Для 4.x надо установить NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json и вместо `JsonSerializer.Serialize` написать `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.